# LoginController not logging in

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to log in users based on my API response.How can I set up my Controller to login users?

I've read the documentation but it doesn't explain how the login function in the controller is actually called or the authenticated function works, just found articles using these functions in the controller.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Library\API;
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    public function username()
    {
        return 'name';
    }
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $APIresponse = API::login($request->all());
        if ($APIresponse->status !== 'logged_in')  return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
        return $this->authenticated($request, auth()->user());
    }

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');

    }
}
```

After someone logs in, they should be redirected to the home page and their name should be displayed in top right corner. Unfortunately, even if I return the 'home' view, their name is not displayed and the user isn't actually logged in (going back to /home will display the login page again).

edit: the views are the default ones that come with php artisan make:auth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $APIresponse = API::login($request->all());
    if ($APIresponse->status !== 'logged_in')  return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
    $this->attemptLogin($request);
    return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
}
```

This will actually log in the users.